# On the asymptotic joint distribution of two weighted Bernoulli sums

Tags: probability, distributions, references, joint-distribution

Let $\theta_i$ be a Bernoulli random variable of success probability $p$.

Given two fixed sets $A = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_N\}$ and $B = \{b_1, b_2, ..., b_N\}$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are constants.

For any realisations $Z = \{\theta_1, \theta_2,..., \theta_N\}$, wee define two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that:

\begin{equation}
X = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i \theta_i
\end{equation}

and,

\begin{equation}
Y = \sum_{i=1}^{N} b_i \theta_i
\end{equation}

Clearly, $X$ and $Y$ are correlated and in the large limit of $N$ each follows a normal distribution with means and variances depending on the fixed sets $A$ and $B$.

**What is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ ?**

I know that if two variables, say  $U$ and $V$, are jointly gaussian, then any linear combination $W = \alpha U + \beta V$ follows a gaussian distribution BUT the converse need not to be true.

However, what is funny with this question is that $X$ and $Y$ is marginally gaussian in the limit of large enough $N$ and the same holds for all linear combinations of the two. If I were to perform a simulation and draw the heatmap the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$, I would get some shape that is not symmetrical with respect to the mean values of $X$ and $Y$ (see figure below where the red dotted lines represents the means of $X$ and $Y$)

[image]

Hence, the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ cannot be gaussian.

Any references or answer to this question would be gladly appreciated.

*We will avoid the trivial case where $A$ and $B$ are identical*

Comment: There is not necessarily any limiting distribution nor, if there is, must it be normal (*e.g.*, consider the cases $a_i=b_i=2^i$ or $a_i=b_i=2^{-i}$) so you must be making some implicit assumptions about the coefficients $A$ and $B.$  What are they?

Comment: @whuber As I  mentionned at the end of the post, A and B are not identical. Hence the condition $a_i  = b_i$  for all $i$ cannot hold. Maybe should I specify that there is no explicit dependency of the coefficients in the index. The true details of what I am trying to solve in my work would be quite difficult to put into a post. Therefore, I assume (most likely naively) that it is easier to consider a problem where the coefficients $A$ and $B$ are just constants with no crazy behavior with respect to index $i$. Also, I mean by limit distribution N being large enough for CLT to be applicable.

Comment: The "not identical" has no effect on my comment.  If you like, set $b_i=3^i$ or $3^{-i}.$ Clearly your abstraction of your actual problem doesn't capture its essential features, so you need to reformulate your question to more closely reflect what your problem is.

Comment: @whuber Then I should admit that I fail to understand the  issue underlined by your original comment in the case of $N$ being finite but very large. If you don't mind explaining, thanks

Comment: You might find it instructive to run some simulations.  This `R` example takes one second to run, for instance: `p <- 1/2;
a <- 2^seq(0, -52);
x <- replicate(1e5, sum(a * rbinom(length(a), 1, p)));
hist(x)`

Comment: @whuber I now understand the implications of your comments. Thank you!
If we try to solve this problem under the assumption that A and B are not identical and the coefficients are such that any realisation of Z yields a unique value to X and Y. One can backtrack from a given X to the realisation of Z and recover Y, thus writing a conditional probability on Y upon knowing X seems to become feasible. However with such conditions in place, I cannot wrap my head around how I would formally write it (as a physicist not a mathematician)

Comment: "Unique value" is a red herring.  You need to focus on the asymptotic behavior of the terms in $A$ and $B.$ Without making any assumptions, there's little you can say.  An example of an effective assumption would be that $A$ and $B$ both converge--I believe that would suffice to invoke a generalization of the CLT--but this is not a necessary assumption.  We couldn't possibly guess what assumptions you might need or are able to make unless you explain what you actual problem is.